# Scalatest accessing Fixture properties

Tags: scala, scalatest

How do I access my `TestSuiteParams` within my `before`?

I am running my tests with `Runner`

```
import org.scalatest.tools.Runner
val runnerArray: Array[String] = Array("-s", "com.inn.org.functional.Stateless", "-Dmonth=1")    
Runner.run(runnerArray)
```

I have the `month` property in `TestSuiteParams` I would like to access in my `before` but I'm not sure how to access it.

Here is how my tests are formatted so far

```
class Stateless extends fixture.FeatureSpec with BeforeAndAfter {

    before("before") {
        // I want to access TestSuiteParams HERE
        // but I cannot!
    }

    feature("feature") {
        scenario() {TestSuiteParams =>
            // this piece works! I can access .month!
            assert(TestSuiteParams.month != null)
        }
    }

    def withFixture(test: OneArgTest): org.scalatest.Outcome = {
        val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
        test(TestSuiteParams(hiveContext, 1)
    }

    case class TestSuiteParams(hiveContext: HiveContext, month: String)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will have to inject the config map into your test class as shown below.

```
import org.scalatest.{ConfigMapWrapperSuite, WrapWith}

@WrapWith(classOf[ConfigMapWrapperSuite])
class Stateless(configMap: Map[String, Any]) extends fixture.FeatureSpec with BeforeAndAfter {
   before("before") {
       configMap("month")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very likely the constructor of your TestClass is failing. can you share your new updated code?

Comment: Sure, thank you for looking into this. I did some more research on my problem and modified some of my code to this http://dpaste.com/0FC1NJ3 However, when I try to run it, the only output I am getting is `*** RUN ABORTED ***`

Comment: isnt this an abstract class? You mean all test classes extends this class IP2GeoTestSuite

Comment: I'm sorry, i c/p the wrong class. It's all the same but just different name. Let me correct this for you! http://dpaste.com/181HGG8 Sorry, really new to scala, and forced onto a scala project...